# Drupal 7 connection to MS SQLServer/PostgreSQL

Tags: database

I'm building an architecture of an integrated system of databases that are going to be the infrastructure of about 60 websites.

since databases are going to be massive (more than 30000 articles will be inserted in the database, thousands of books and its abstraction and etc) I'm really worry about the efficiency and ability of MySQL to handle the data.

I'm not very experienced in the theory of Database Management System, so this is my question, Can MySQL handle this amount of data? if not Can Drupal 7 connect to MSSQL Server and work with it as good as it works with MySQL? what about PostgreSQL?

Thanks

Comment: Whenever MySQL can handle that amount of data is a question that is not specific to Drupal.

Comment: `Can Drupal 7 connect to MSSQL Server and work with it as good as it works with MySQL` I asked this here because the one who answers the quesion must have a background knowledge of Drupal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can MySQL handle this amount of data?

Yes, MySQL can theoretically handle many millions of rows (see [How many rows in a database are TOO MANY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926079/how-many-rows-in-a-database-are-too-many)).

What actually matter are your server resources, configuration, and indexes. If you're not sure about the first two, consult with a professional dba who will be able to help you fine tune your settings for both Drupal, and, more importantly, the specific usage of your app.

Drupal core tables are heavily indexed (as are many tables provided by contrib modules), so it'll probably come down to the custom/contrib modules you have installed from that respect.

> if not Can Drupal 7 connect to MSSQL Server and work with it as good as it works with MySQL? what about PostgreSQL?

Yes, Drupal can use both MSSQL and PostgreSQL. How well any of those perform will entirely depend on the same things mentioned above. I doubt you'd see massive differences in any of them, unless your app is used in a particular way that one or another is better suited for (but the only way to work that out is by benchmarking).